# JavaScript/jQuery one variable used in two functions best solution ? Example

Tags: jquery, variables, global

I'm somehow confused. What is the best way to use one variable as global in jQuery - just to use it two click function ? Here is the code :

> http://jsfiddle.net/DyqdA/

HTML :

```
<div id = "div1">DIV # 1</div>
    <div id = "div2">DIV # 2</div>
    <input type = "button" value = "Click to see whick div you've chosen."/>
    <h1></h1>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var answer;
    $("#div1").click(function(event) { 
        window.answer = "FIRST";
    }); 

    $("div2").click(function(event) { 
        window.answer = "SECOND";
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
        $("h1").html(window.answer);
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

CSS :

```
#div1 {
    background-color: red; 
    height: 50px;
}
#div2 {
    background-color: blue; 
     height: 50px;
}
```

I need to SAVE text to the answer variable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is working fine, but your fiddle isn't working because the anonymous scope misses an opening bracket, and because you've written `div2` instead of `#div2`, so the second div doesn't have a click event. [Your code, fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/S9Qm9/)

Comment: @DavidHedlund, in your case, it is unnecessary to declare the 'answer' var as `window` is already global (and really unrelated to the declared var)

Comment: Unrelated to your variable question, note that using clickable divs makes your page unusable for people who choose not to or are physically unable to use a mouse or other pointing device. Better to use anchor tags since these can be accessed via the keyboard (of course you can still style them).

Comment: @smerny: Sure, I'm not really advocating anything, but OP's question is about how to make a variable global, and I'm just suggesting that perhaps the error here is not that the variable isn't global, but rather a missing `(` and `#`. If the minor syntax errors were not in the fiddle, OP might not have asked the question at all, because the code would've worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DyqdA/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var answer;
    $("#div1").click(function(event) { 
        answer = "FIRST";
    }); 

    $("#div2").click(function(event) { 
        answer = "SECOND";
    });

    $("#displayDivButton").click(function() {
        $("h1").html(answer);
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

you were using ("button") but didnt have any "button" tag, you were also using ("div2") instead of ("#div2")... then you can just drop the window as you declared the answer var within the scope of all 3 functions

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `window.` since this variable isn't global.  It is accessible in the context you are trying to use it in:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var answer;
    $("#div1").click(function(event) { 
        answer = "FIRST";
    }); 

    $("#div2").click(function(event) { 
        answer = "SECOND";
    });

    $("input").click(function() {
        $("h1").html(answer);
    }); 
});
```

EDIT:  And drop that `(jQuery)` at the end.

EDIT2:  Also, `div2` should be `#div2` and you don't have a `button` in your html, you have an `input` of type `button`.

Answer (score 0):

hope you are expecting this:

```
myVar="Global Scope";

family = function(){

 var myVar="member";

member1= function() {
    console.log(myVar);
};

member2= function() {
    myVar = "member2";
    console.log(myVar);
  };

  member1();
  member2();

};

family();
console.log(myVar);
```